# Почему код так работает?

Tags: javascript

```
return Array(n).fill(Array(n).fill(0)).map(($arrV, $i) => {$arrV.splice($i,1,1);
```

я хочу чтобы выводил что то похожее: [[1,0,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0,0],[0,0,1,0,0], [0,0,0,1,0], [0,0,0,0,1]]

а он заполняет все массивы единицами. Почему?

Answer (score 2):

[fill ()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill)

> Метод `fill()` заполняет все элементы массива от начального до конечного индексов одним значением.

Одним – в смысле одним и тем же (в оригинале static value). То есть

```
Array(n).fill(Array(n).fill(0))
```

равносильно следующему:

```
const x = Array(n).fill(0); Array(n).fill(x)
```

Из чего немедленно следует, что все элементы результата *ссылаются* на одно и то же, *единственное* значение.

```js
const f = n => Array (n).fill (Array (n).fill (0)), a = f (2)

console.log (a)

console.assert (a [0] !== a [1])
```

Поэтому код в `map` на каждом проходе изменяет один и то же массив, что вы и имеете неудовольствие наблюдать.

Решить можно по-разному, например так:

```js
const f = n => Array.from ({length: n}, () => Array (n).fill (0)).map ((a, i) => (a [i] = 1, a))

console.log (f (3))
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот так `Array(n).fill(Array(n))`
Вы заполняете первый массив одним и тем же экземпляром массива 2

Вот рабочий сниппет:

```js
let n = 5;
let mat = Array(n).fill(0).map(($arrV, $i) => Array(n).fill(0).fill(1, $i, $i+1));
console.log(mat)
```

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что каждый ваш подмассив в массиве имеет одинаковую ссылку друг на друга, в результате чего, изменяя любой из них, вы изменяете и все остальные. Чтобы создать независимые подмассивы используйте метод `Array.from()`.

Рабочий пример:

```
let arr = Array(5).fill(Array(5).fill(0));
arr = arr.map(value => {
  return Array.from(value);
});
arr.map((value, k) => {
  return value.splice(k, 1, 1);
});
```